# Criteria range in SUMIFS array formula

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets, sumifs

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Spend",SUMIFS(Expenses!G:G,Expenses!D:D,A:A,Expenses!B:B,"Budget")))
```

Doesn't produce a result

If I change the criteria that was "A:A" to a certain field it works

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Spend",SUMIFS(Expenses!G:G,Expenses!D:D,"A1",Expenses!B:B,"Budget")))
```

If I use simple SUMIF the first version also works

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Spend",SUMIF(Expenses!D:D,A:A,Expenses!G:G)))
```

How come not as SUMIFS?

Comment: Excel or Google-Spreadsheets? They are *not* the same thing and having both tags is misleading.

Comment: I hoped to find a formula that works in both ,more important would be Google-Spreadsheets.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve it this I suppose?
If A1 = B AND C1 = D then sum E (but in an array)
With SUMIF it works but not with SUMIFS

Answer (score 0):

could it be u need to use sumproduct() function?  you probably need to know which Excel version you are in.

if before 2007 SUMIFS() won't work.

rr

Comment: Actually I'm on Google Sheets, I will look into sumproduct() but am unfamiliar with it.