# Count cell in a row if is not empty in a none consecutive range of four columns google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking get the count of each row where the cells are not empty in a none sequential range (A3:A;C3:C;E3:E;G3:G) .
Say if A3 is not empty and C3, E3, G3 is empty than the result would be 1
Say if A3 and C3 is not empty and E3, G3 is empty than the result would be 2
Say if A3 , C3 and E3 is not empty and G3 is empty than the result would be 3

I like that done for the entire range.

BASICLY COUNT EACH CELL WITH ANY VALUE ON EACH ROW AND RETURN THE RESULTS OF THAT ROW.

I need the same results as =countA(A3:G) for each row inoring columns(B,D,F) in some type of an arrayformula.

Thanks for the help in advance

Wilson

link to the sheet:
[LINK TO SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h6Mi0A_nr7IHhx1cTXWGXW43pI2-rnZxdHqk9-QgA08/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A3:A); MMULT(N({A3:A\C3:C\ E3:E\ G3:G}<>""); {1; 1; 1; 1});))
```

Or, in a more general approach (filtering out the odd columns)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A); MMULT(N(A3:G<>""); N(TRANSPOSE(ISODD(COLUMN(A3:G3)))));))
```

Comment: You could probably update your answers [COUNTA in current row in an array formula (Google Sheets)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30395824) on how to dismiss the `0`'s

Comment: Thank you for the help. The first formula is perfect!

Comment: Hey @JPV :) Saw this on the google forums.  you can 0 out the "don't count this column" columns, but using the second matrix in the mmult without worrying about the first. like this: =ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(MMULT(N(A3:G<>"");{1;0;1;0;1;0;1});COUNTA(A3:A);1))

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula :

```
=Arrayformula(IF(A3:A<>"",1,0)+IF(C3:C<>"",1,0)+IF(E3:E<>"",1,0)+IF(G3:G<>"",1,0))
```

Comment: That's it, almost perfect, thank you! Just one adjustment if possible. How do I remove the 0's if the row is empty?

Comment: @user2916405 Just replace all the `0`'s with `""`. `=Arrayformula(IF(A3:A<>"",1,"")+IF(C3:C<>"",1,"")+IF(E3:E<>"",1,"")+IF(G3:G<>"",1,""))`